Show that $\forall x,y \in (a,b):x<y\iff-\left(\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x-b}\right) <-\left(\frac{1}{y-a}+\frac{1}{y-b}\right)$
Let $a<b, (a,b \in \mathbb{R})$
I want to show that there is an homeomorphism $f$ between $(a,b)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x < y \iff f(x) < f(y)$, $(x,y \in (a,b))$, but I don't want to use the $\text{tan}(x)$ function.
The reason for this is because I want to extend $f$ to an homeomorphism between $[a,b]$ and $[-\infty, \infty]$ that preserves the order in the most elementary way possible.
I saw on page 342 of Bourbaki's General Topology Part 1 that the following function appears to have the properties I'm looking for:
$f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto f(x) = -\left (\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x-b}\right)$
The problem is that Boubaki doesn't show that $f$ is strictly increasing, nor even that $f^{-1}$ is, and I'm having trouble to prove it by myself.
If you already know that f is strictly increasing, then by calculating its inverse you can easily conclude that $f$ is bijective, and $f$ is therefore an homeomorphism, as it is any monotonic (extended-real valued) bijective function with domain and codomain being intervals.
I would be very grateful, if anyone can help me show that for all $x,y \in (a,b) $: $$ x < y \iff  - \left(\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x-b}\right)<-\left(\frac{1}{y-a}+\frac{1}{y-b}\right)$$

Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. To show that $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b)$, compute its derivative and show that it is positive on this interval.

The derivative of
$$-\left(\frac1{x-a}+\frac1{x-b}\right)$$
with respect to $x$ is
$$\frac1{(x-b)^2}+\frac1{(x-a)^2}$$
which is clearly always positive.
Also, $f(x)=-\left(\frac1{x-a}+\frac1{x-b}\right)$ is continuous and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$.
This implies $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b)$.

Another possible approach.
To begin with, notice that:
\begin{align*}
a < x < y < b & \Longleftrightarrow 0 < x - a < y - a \\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 0 < \frac{1}{y - a} < \frac{1}{x - a}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{x - a} - \frac{1}{y - a} > 0
\end{align*}
Similarly, it does also hold the relation:
\begin{align*}
a < x < y < b & \Longleftrightarrow x - b < y - b < 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{y - b} < \frac{1}{x - b}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{x - b} - \frac{1}{y - b} > 0
\end{align*}
whence it may be concluded that the proposed inequality is true.
Hopefully this helps!
